# Is there a way to make text selectable in powerpoint slideshow

Tags: powerpoint

I've created a presentation in powerpoint 2013 and need to make the text selectable (for copy/paste purposes) during presentation mode (it will be used in kiosk mode ultimately). Is there a way to do this with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but if you only want to get the text from certain shapes, you can assign the shapes a RunMacro Action Setting. For example, you could have it run this macro as a demo:

```
Sub GrabTheText(oSh as Shape)
   MsgBox oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
End Sub
```

That will give you a reference to the clicked shape in oSh so you can do whatever you like with it.
Obviously, you won't want to assign the action setting to any shape that doesn't or cannot hold text, else the macro will error.  Or you could go wild and assign it to everything and add error handling code to the macro.